# initState() gets called when navigating to a new page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Okay, so, I have this class (`IntroPageAnimation`) which extends PageRouteBuilder which I use for animating my page transitions.
I pass 2 Widgets, namely the current page (`exitPage`) and the page to which the app should navigate (`enterPage`).

```
class IntroPageAnimation extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget enterPage;
  final Widget exitPage;

  IntroPageAnimation({required this.enterPage, required this.exitPage})
      : super(
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secAnimation, child) {
      animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);

      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0, 0),
              end: Offset(0, -1),
            ).animate(animation),
            child: exitPage,
          ),
          SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0, 1),
              end: Offset(0, 0),
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secAnimation) {
      return enterPage;
    },
  );
}
```

I use it like this, inside an `onClick`, inside of the `build` function of my main page:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(IntroPageAnimation(
  enterPage: VeryCoolNewPage(),
  exitPage: this.widget,
));
```

But my problem is: **every time I navigate to that new page, `initState()` is called on `exitPage`**. How do I prevent that from happening?

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/9ef5c1b32823) on how to create page transitions.

Answer (score 0):

it is calling because of  `this.widget`
replace

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(IntroPageAnimation(
            enterPage: VeryCoolNewPage(),
            exitPage: this.widget,
          ));
```

with

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(IntroPageAnimation(
            enterPage: VeryCoolNewPage(),
            exitPage: EmptyWidget(),
          ));
```

Comment: I would like to animate the `exitPage`, as well. Using an empty widget, that's not going to work. (right?)

Comment: if you call `exitPage`, means it will build from start :), and there `initState` will be called

Comment: Yeah, but I do *not* want to rebuild `exitPage`. I just want to animate the current page in its current state as well as the page which is being navigated to.